# How to center a block text and keeping it left aligned and numbering the individual lines?

Tags: formatting, lists

This must be a very newbie question, but I still find the LaTeX documentation hard to access.

Given the following MWE listing some properties of the moduli of complex numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    $-|z| \le \Re{z} \le |z|$ \\
    $-|z| \le \Im{z} \le |z|$ \\
    $|z| \ge 0$ \\
    $|z|=0 \Leftrightarrow z=0$ \\
    $|z| = |-z| = |\overline{z}|$ \\
    $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$\\
    $|z_1 z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$\\
    $|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$\\
    $|z^{-1}|=|z|^{-1}$\\
    $|\frac{z_1}{z_2}| = \frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$\\
    $|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 - z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$
\end{document}
```

I would like to center the lines but keep the lines left aligned.

I would also like to number the lines. Can this be done automatically, so that inserting a property later does not require re-numbering and checking references elsewhere in the document?

Comment: Using a centered `tabular` environment? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displayed math is normally numbered in LaTeX and the `amsmath` provide a couple of usable environments. Search `amsmath` manual and you can find the user's manual with good description. For this case I would suggest to put it in an `align` environment with alignment to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}
  &-|z| \le \Re{z} \le |z|\\
  &-|z| \le \Im{z} \le |z|\\
  &|z| \ge 0 \label{prop:non-negative}\\
  &|z|=0 \Leftrightarrow z=0\\
  &|z| = |-z| = |\overline{z}|\\
  &z\overline{z}=|z|^2 \nonumber\\
  &|z_1 z_2|=|z_1||z_2|\\
  &|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|\label{prop:inequality-++}\\
  &|z^{-1}|=|z|^{-1}\\
  &|\frac{z_1}{z_2}| = \frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}\\
  &|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 - z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|
\end{align}
Property~\ref{prop:non-negative} is important, but
inequality~\ref{prop:inequality-++} is also frequently needed.

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `lipsum` stuff in the code is just to get some text. The example also shows how suppress numbers (put a `\nonumber` command in this line), how to assign a label to a line (with the `\label` command), and how to use the labels to refer to the line anywhere in the document (with the `\ref` command; see the text immediately below the numbered lines).

Comment: This is exactly how I had it in mind, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is a list environment. One way to get it centered is to use [the `varwidth`  environment](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth) and center that:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}%[nosep]
    \item $-|z| \le \Re{z} \le |z|$
    \item $-|z| \le \Im{z} \le |z|$
    \item $|z| \ge 0$
    \item $|z|=0 \Leftrightarrow z=0$
    \item $|z| = |-z| = |\overline{z}|$
    \item $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$
    \item $|z_1 z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$
    \item $|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$
    \item $|z^{-1}|=|z|^{-1}$
    \item $|\frac{z_1}{z_2}| = \frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$
    \item $|z_1|-|z_2| \le |z_1 - z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$
\end{enumerate}
\end{varwidth}\hfill\null{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an individual list of formulae, numbered on the left like `enumerate`, independently from the equation counter, here is a solution with an environment based on `tabularx`. I added some improvements, mainly the use of  `\widebar`, from `mathabx`, which is better than `\overline`, and an `\abs` command, with variable-sized  vertical lines:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\abs}[1]{}{\lvert}{\rvert}{\vphantom{#1}}{#1}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<5><6><7><8><9><10>
<10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>
mathx10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}
\let\conj\widebar
\newcounter{rowno}
\newenvironment{formlist}{%
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\par\vspace*{\topsep}
\centering\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{\refstepcounter{rowno}\eqmakebox[Rno][r]{\therowno.}}l >{\centering\everymath{\displaystyle}\arraybackslash$}X <{$}}}%
{\endtabularx\vspace{\dimexpr\topsep + \partopsep}}

\begin{document}

Text text tex text text. Text text tex text text. Text text tex text text. Text text tex text text. Text text tex text text. Text text tex text text.

\begin{formlist}
 & -\abs{z} \le \Re{z} \le \abs{z} \\
 & -\abs{z} \le \Im{z} \le \abs{z} \\
 & \abs{z} \ge 0 \\
 & \abs{z}=0 \iff z=0 \\
 & \abs{z} = \abs{-z} = \abs{\conj{z}} \\
 & z \widebar{z}=\abs{z}^2 \\
 & \abs{z_1 z_2}=\abs{z_1}\abs{z_2} \\
 & \abs[\big]{\abs{z_1}-\abs{z_2}} \le \abs{z_1 + z_2} \le \abs{z_1}+\abs{z_2} \\
 & \abs*{z^{-1}}=\abs{z}^{-1} \\
 & \abs[\Big]{\frac{z_1}{z_2}} = \frac{\abs{z_1}}{\abs{z_2}} \\
 & \abs[\big]{\abs{z_1}-\abs{z_2}} \le \abs{z_1 - z_2} \le \abs{z_1}+\abs{z_2}
\end{formlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but in this example I lose the left alignment. I should have specified clearly in the question that I would like the numbering on the right side, which is quite standard in most texts.

Comment: This was not clear really: equation numbers is not the same as line numbers. That said, the norm in some countries (e. g. France) is to have equation numbers on the left side). You might interested by some improvements to typesetting the modulusor the conjugate of a complex number, though.